# Bypass some packet layers in Python Scapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, packet, scapy

I want to construct an IP packet with Vlan part.
It's easily done with Scapy:

```
from scapy import inet
newpkt = inet.Ether()/inet.Dot1Q()/inet.IP()
```

Sometimes I want to have `inet.Dot1Q()` in the packet, sometimes no.
What should be the default value for `inet.Dot1Q()` so it's simply bypassed in the operator '/'?
I tried `''` and `None` - they don't work.

```
from scapy import inet
myDot1Q = SOME DEFAULT VALUE
newpkt = inet.Ether()/myDot1Q/inet.IP()
#new packet is a valid IP packet here
```

**EDIT: A different explanation of my problem**

1) I can create a packet with VLAN tag

```
inet.Ether()/inet.Dot1Q/inet.IP()
```

2) I can create a packet with double VLAN tag

```
inet.Ether()/inet.Dot1Q/inet.Dot1Q/inet.IP()
```

3) How can I build a packet that may be an untagged packet, VLAN tagged packet or double VLAN tagged packet? It would be great to have something like:

```
#No VLAN
myVlan = ???
myDoubleVlan = ???

#VLAN
myVlan = inet.Dot1Q()
myDoubleVlan = ???

#Double VLAN
myVlan = inet.Dot1Q()
myDoubleVlan = inet.Dot1Q()

#In any case the packet structure should remain the same
inet.Ether()/myVlan/myDoubleVlan/inet.IP()
```

I can't figure out what the default value `???` should be to be able to properly construct the packet.

Comment: Still looking for the good solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I just can't think of any reason why you wouldn't use a simple solution like this:

```
# example for single Vlan
# myVlan = Dot1Q()
# myDoubleVlan = None

# generate the package
package = Ether()
if myVlan: package /= myVlan
if myDoubleVlan: package /= myDoubleVlan
package /= IP()
```

But anyway, if this approach is for whatever reason not acceptable, there is another possibility...
You could override the `Packet` class and create your own class that is neutral to the division operator. The only thing you need is to override the `__div__` method and to add some parentheses to preserve the right precedence.

This is how you would implement it:

```
from scapy.all import *

class NeutralPacket(Packet):
    def __init__(self,  _pkt="", _internal=0, **fields):
        super(NeutralPacket, self).__init__(_pkt, _internal, **fields)
    def __div__(self, other):
        return other

#No VLAN
myVlan = NeutralPacket()
myDoubleVlan = NeutralPacket()

#VLAN
myVlan = Dot1Q()
myDoubleVlan = NeutralPacket()

#Double VLAN
myVlan = Dot1Q()
myDoubleVlan = Dot1Q()

# this part doesn't need to change, but you need to have two
# additional parenthesis for proper precedence
Ether()/(myVlan/(myDoubleVlan/IP()))
```

#### Additional explanation:

The `__div__()` method is the division `operator` implementation. The interpreter executes `a/b` as `a.__div__(b)`, and the `Packet` class has its own implementation of this operator. If you take a look at its [code](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/scapy/1.0.2/classscapy_1_1_packet.html#ad356ffbd896ca3532f72dc1eb038a59a), you can see that its basically appending the `payload` of package `b` to package `a`.
What we are doing here instead is just returning the `other` package, being `b` in this case, effectively ignoring `a` completely.
Note that this works only in one direction, when `NeutralPacket` is the left-hand-side operator, because otherwise it's some other's class' `__div__()` method being executed. To handle this, we have to add parenthesis so that the precedence will make our `NeutralPacket` class always be the left-hand-side operator. And since this doesn't effect the overall result due to `Packet`'s implementation, this works nicely for your case. The only thing that wouldn't work is if the `NeutralPacket` would be the most right-hand-side (i.e. the last) operator, since then you couldn't force the right precedence. But for VLAN this is not an issue, since there are always layers above it..

Answer (score 1):

I had completely forgotten about `Raw()`.

The `Raw` layer is what you want.

`Raw()`, if no data is placed there, will add nothing to your constructed Packet. You can use this as a default value for your `myDot1Q` variable.

```
>>> b = Raw() / ICMP()
>>> a = Raw() / ICMP()
>>> b = ICMP()
>>> a.show()
###[ Raw ]###
  load= ''
###[ ICMP ]###
     type= echo-request
     code= 0
     chksum= None
     id= 0x0
     seq= 0x0
>>> b.show()
###[ ICMP ]###
  type= echo-request
  code= 0
  chksum= None
  id= 0x0
  seq= 0x0
>>> a.build()
'\x08\x00\xf7\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> b.build()
'\x08\x00\xf7\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> a.build() == b.build()
True
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to have a generic scapy packet, like `inet.Ether()/firstDot1Q/secondDot1Q/thirdDot1Q/inet.IP()`. Sometimes I do need double etc VLAN, sometimes not

Comment: What do you mean by a generic Scapy packet?

Comment: I meant the construction like this: `inet.Ether()/firstDot1Q/secondDot1Q/thirdDot1Q/inet.IP()`. The aforementioned line is the same all the time, however I'd like to have thirdDot1Q = VOID or WHATEVER so it becomes invisible and the packet is constructed properly without considering this part

Comment: Have no problem with constructing scapy packets, it's just a bit ugly to construct all the packets from scratch without the possibility of reusing them like I mentioned before

Comment: If that latest edit doesn't address your question, please post more detail about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I explained the question a bit differently

Comment: Got it - `Raw()` should do what you want.

Comment: Hello! I tried your solution but it doesn't work as I expected. For example: `b = inet.Ether()/inet.Raw()/inet.Dot1Q()/inet.IP()` - this line doesn't work properly. Ether() and Dot1Q() don't concatenate properly (as if there is no Raw() between them)

Comment: What happens? - Update your answer.

Comment: Also - you should be importing Scapy with `from scapy import *`